# Не получается реализовать метод equalsIgnoreCase в ListView с адаптером

Tags: java, android, listview

Я недавно начал разбираться с ListView с адаптером, у меня есть поиск и я хочу, чтобы он игнорировал большие буквы (если пишут маленькими). вот код

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged (CharSequence s,int start, int count, int after) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged (CharSequence s,int start, int before, int count) {
        if (s.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            searchItems(s.toString());
            initList();
        } else {
            searchItems(s.toString());
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged (Editable s) {
    }
});
}
public void initList() {
    items = array.elemetnExtr;
    listitems = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(items));
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.txtitem, listitems);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

public void searchItems(String textToSearch) {
    for (String item : items) {
        if (!item.contains(textToSearch)) {
            listitems.remove(item);
        }
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```